# Testing Flask pytest is stacked without error

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm trying to create tests on Flask Python.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_app():
    app = create_app('config')
    with app.run(port=5001,debug=True) as test_client:
        print("create_app")
        yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def token(test_app):
    with test_app.test_client() as client:
        TEST_ADMIN = os.environ['TEST_ADMIN']
        TEST_PASSWORD = os.environ['TEST_PASSWORD']
        req = {"username":TEST_ADMIN,"password":TEST_PASSWORD}
        response = client.post('/api/login/', json=req)
        token = response.json['access_token']
    print(f"token ")
    return token

def test_index(test_app,token):
    res = test_app.get('/test/')
    assert res.status_code == 200
    expected = {"code":"200"}
    assert expected == json.loads(res.get_data(as_text=True))
```

This test is stacked with "tests/test_admin.py::test_index" and doesn't move forward, no error or success. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it hangs on. `app.run()` should be starting a server which would explain why it hangs but I got other problems with your example.

Instead, here is a minimalist example of what I think you should be doing and that is:

1. Create a test context for your app using `test_request_context()`.
2. Use `test_client()` method of a `Flask` instance to create a client that can call the app's endpoints.

```py
import json
import pytest
from flask import Flask


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.add_url_rule("/test/", "test", lambda: {"code": "200"})

    with app.test_request_context():
        yield app.test_client()


def test_index(client):
    res = client.get("/test/")
    assert res.status_code == 200
    expected = {"code": "200"}
    assert expected == json.loads(res.get_data(as_text=True))
```